# Create XML with integrated CSS & DTD

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml, dtd

I would like a short code example please of a xml file with integrated DTD and CSS Styles.

All in one file.

One element is enough.

P.s.: I'm xml newbie and couldn't find a example with xml and css in one file.

Regards

Ps.: I would need such css functions in the xml file:

```
element {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:600px;
  background-color:#999999;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-family:Tahoma,Arial;
  font-size:40px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to the edited question. The answer would be basically an application of the previous answer, just with the specific stylesheet and element name substituted, but here I also illustrate how a `data:` URL could be used to embed an external stylesheet. (I don’t think it makes much sense, but it addresses the question, and maybe there is a specific reason for asking for a single-file solution.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href=
"data:text/css,element{position:relative;display:block;width:600px;background-color:%23999999;color:%23FFFFFF;font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-size:40px;padding:15px;}"
?>
<!DOCTYPE demo [
<!ELEMENT demo (element)>
<!ELEMENT element (#PCDATA)>
]>
<demo>
<element>Hello world</element>
</demo>
```

Note: In the `data:` URL, the “#” character (U+0023) has been %-encoded as `%23`.

Comment: Thank you, I have to admit, you have the most professional answers to programing question I have ever read. I like the "I don’t think it makes much sense, but it addresses the question, and maybe there is a specific reason for asking for a single-file solution." part!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE demo [
<!ELEMENT demo (style, body)>
<!ELEMENT style (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>
<demo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>body { color: red }</style>
<body>Hello world</body>
</demo>
```

This is a bit trickery, since the `xmlns` attribute suggests HTML interpretation of tags, making a browser recognized the `style` element as containing a CSS stylesheet. More normally, you would use XML tools that are independent of HTML. This means that the stylesheet would be in an external file, say mystyle.css, and you could write just

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE demo [
<!ELEMENT demo (body)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>
<demo>
<body>Hello world</body>
</demo>
```